# Google tests runtime undefined reference

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, clion

I'm able to run the Google tests setup in the official [Jetbrains Clion guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/unit-testing-tutorial.html) using `TEST_F` macros but I'm not able to setup the same environment for my project. The following is the test class I'm trying to run, everytime I refer to the `ed1` instance I get a bunch of `undefined reference` errors.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "../NetworkServer.h"

class SharedEditorTest : public ::testing::Test {

protected:

    virtual void SetUp() {

        ed1 = new SharedEditor(server);

        /*ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('a'), std::string{"0_1"}, std::vector<int>{1}));
        ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('n'), std::string{"0_2"}, std::vector<int>{2}));
        ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('t'), std::string{"0_3"}, std::vector<int>{3}));
        ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('o'), std::string{"0_4"}, std::vector<int>{4}));
        ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('n'), std::string{"0_5"}, std::vector<int>{5}));
        ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('i'), std::string{"0_6"}, std::vector<int>{6}));
        ed1->getSymbols().push_back(Symbol(char('o'), std::string{"0_7"}, std::vector<int>{7}));
        std::cout << "ed1: " << ed1->to_string() << std::endl;*/
    }

    virtual void TearDown() {

    }

    NetworkServer server;
    SharedEditor* ed1{};
};


TEST_F(SharedEditorTest, TestName) {
    std::cout << ed1->getCounter() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Output

```
CMakeFiles\Google_Tests_run.dir/objects.a(SharedEditorTest.cpp.obj): In function `SharedEditorTest_TestName_Test::TestBody()':
D:/asant/workspace/CLionProjects/CRDTpp/Google_tests/SharedEditorTest.cpp:36: undefined reference to `SharedEditor::getCounter() const'
CMakeFiles\Google_Tests_run.dir/objects.a(SharedEditorTest.cpp.obj): In function `SharedEditorTest::SetUp()':
D:/asant/workspace/CLionProjects/CRDTpp/Google_tests/SharedEditorTest.cpp:14: undefined reference to `SharedEditor::SharedEditor(NetworkServer&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Google_tests\CMakeFiles\Google_Tests_run.dir\build.make:89: Google_tests/Google_Tests_run.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:125: Google_tests/CMakeFiles/Google_Tests_run.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:132: Google_tests/CMakeFiles/Google_Tests_run.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:176: Google_Tests_run] Error 2
```

You can access the full project cloning this [repo](https://github.com/anphetamina/CRDTpp).

EDIT1:

[image]

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(CRDTpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(Google_tests)
add_executable(CRDTpp "main.cpp" "Symbol.cpp" "Symbol.h" "NetworkServer.cpp" "NetworkServer.h" "SharedEditor.cpp" "SharedEditor.h" "Message.cpp" "Message.h")
```

`Google_tests\CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Google_tests)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_subdirectory(lib)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(Google_Tests_run SharedEditorTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run gtest gtest_main)
```

Comment: Shouw us your build system (`CMakeLists.txt`, `MakeFile` or whatever you are using). Issue is likely there.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen check EDIT1

Comment: Can you show which references are undefined? No idea what is missing as you did not provide the info. Is it missing gtest, stl, clib or ... ?

Comment: @Klaus down under the code there is the output

Comment: Where did you specify to link with the object containing SharedEditor code ?

Comment: Have you implemented `SharedEditor::getCounter`?

Comment: @Gojita do you mean linking Google_tests with my source files?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes

Comment: I could just supose that, somewhere, there's the code of SharedEditor::getCounter. Perhaps have you done a library with it ... don't know. But, you should link your Google_Tests_run with the object countaining the getCounter code. SharedEditor.cpp is only compiled to create an executable, but you did not create a library. Add it also in add_executable of your Google_Tests_run or create a library